# I want to convert a string into list

Tags: python

I am giving a string like `d='direct'`
expected o/p= match found for direct
but i am getting like match not found for d
match not found for i, match not found for r etc.
 for now i am using a code:

```
dict1={'d': 'direct', 't': '2',  'g': ['D','D']}
dict2={'d': 'direct', 'u': ['2', '2'], 't': ['2', '2'],  'g': ['D', 'D']}

for key in dict1:
    for index, element in enumerate(dict1[key]):
        if element in dict2[key]:
            print("Match found for", element)
        else:
            print("Match not found for", element)
```

Comment: Huh? Can you be a little more clear please?

Comment: Dict has 2 things, keys and values, you want to check valued of one dict to valued of another dict? or keys?

Comment: value of one dict to value of another dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
dict1={'d': 'direct', 't': '2',  'g': ['D','D']}
dict2={'d': 'direct', 'u': ['2', '2'], 't': ['2', '2'],  'g': ['D', 'D']}

for key1 in dict1:
   for key2 in dict2:
        if key1 in key2:
            print dict1[key1]
```

You are iterating over the dict1, which compares the individual chars.

Answer (score 1):

`dict1[key]` returns `'direct'`.  Try:

```
for i in 'direct':
   print(i)
```

You'll find that it prints:
    d
    i
    r
    ....

That's what your code is doing:

```
match not found for d
match not found for i
match not found for r etc
```

Iterating over a string gives you the individual characters.

Changing `dict1` to

```
dict1={'d': ['direct'], ...}
```

will at least get you past the 1st key.  Assuming, that is, you want to test for 'direct' in the second dictionary.  Make the same change in `dict2`.  In other words, be careful about mixing up strings and lists.  Sometimes a string behaves like a list.

Look also at `list('direct')`, or `for i in list('direct'):...`.  That's probably not the string to list conversion that you want - but sometimes it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this below op what you want?

```
dict1={'d': 'direct', 't': '2',  'g': ['D','D']}
dict2={'d': 'direct', 'u': ['2', '2'], 't': ['2', '2'],  'g': ['D', 'D']}

#for key in dict1:
    #print key

for key in dict1:
    for index, element in enumerate(dict1[key]):
        #print key, index, element
        if element in dict2:
            print("Element {0} found".format(element))
        else:
            print("Element {0} not found".format(element))
```

Element d found
Element i not found
Element r not found
Element e not found
Element c not found
Element t found
Element D not found
Element D not found
Element 2 not found